# Cut the graph periodically and find mean of overall graph using one final graph

Tags: python, pandas, graph, error-handling, overlapping

I have a csv file with 16474 rows with torque in the first column and date time in the second. I want to cut the plot periodically and plot on one graph. Then I need to find out the mean of the overall graph.

Comment: I've tried to make the English clearer, but I don't know what tools the OP would like to use, which will make this question difficult to answer.

Comment: i have one csv file so, first i plot the graph. now i need to cut the graph into equal parts like 4 parts and then combine into one graph thats all

Comment: What tool or language are you intending to use? Python, r?

Comment: Pyhton and panda

Comment: Do u have any idea about this problem please tell me i am waiting for your response.